# Using StyleRef to reference text contained in a document Header

Tags: microsoft-word, bookmarks, styles, headers, cross-reference

I am attempting to reference text that is located in the header to be repeated throughout the body of the document in Microsoft Word 2010.  I would like to avoid using Bookmarks, because others will be updating this file and I am concerned they will accidentally delete the reference when changing the Bookmark.

It seems that I cannot use StyleRef to reference text located in the header, because I receive an "Error! No text of specified style in document", even though I created a unique style and only have one string that should apply.  Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: I have created a temporary solution, although it is not the most preferable method - I simply created a title page (which is not printed with the entire document) that contains the StyleRef text which is referenced throughout the body and header. The references are updated when highlighting all of the text (with Ctrl + A) and selecting F9, however if there is another solution that allows me to simply change one of the headers and then update references throughout the document from the header, that would be preferred.